# Set height of element to height of element with % height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height, css-position

I want to set the height of element chatbox to the height of element videobox. But I don't know how to do that. I would be also nice if you send me a method without using JavaScript.

Code:

```css
#content {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  min-width: 900px;
  margin: 80px auto;
}
#stream {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}
#video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div style="width:75%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;" id="videobox">
    <div id="stream">
      <iframe id="video" src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=marmeladenoma" height="720" width="1280" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true">
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:25%;float:right;display:inline-block;background-color:rgb(3, 40, 74)" id="chatbox">
    hi
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `display` of `#content` to `flex` and then the `height` of `#chatbox` to `inherit`. That is:

```
#content {
    display: flex;
    ...
}

#chatbox {
    height: inherit;
    ...
}
```

So, the resultant styling rules in full are:

```
#content {
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    min-width: 900px;
    margin: 80px auto;
}
#stream {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
}
#video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#chatbox {
    height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the height of the `videobox` (because it's variable) and can't set it explicitly in the CSS, you have to use JavaScript to help by getting the height of the `videobox` and setting the `chatbox` to be the same. Here's a simple example using jQuery:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var h = $('#videobox').outerHeight();
  $('#chatbox').css('height', h);
};
```

http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/WoQdPz

Otherwise you could use `flexbox` with `stretch` to help you out. See:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

If you can put both elements in the same parent div.

Then you can set the height of the containing div and use height:100% on both elements.

If you can't put them in the same div, you'll have to either use javascript or set the height of both elements to an exact number of pixels.